# Scaladoc 2.11.8 API incomplete?

Tags: scala, scaladoc

[Scala API 2.10.2](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.10.2/#package) shows indexes for some packages such as [scala.util.parsing.json](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.10.2/scala/util/parsing/json/package.html) and [scala.xml](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.10.2/scala/xml/package.html)

[Scala API 2.11.8](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.11.8/#package) doesn't show those packages. But the code does exist in Scala 2.11.

```
scala.util.parsing.json.JSONArray(List("Banana", "Yogurt", "Coffee"))
//res0: scala.util.parsing.json.JSONArray = ["Banana", "Yogurt", "Coffee"]
```

Is there anyway to get the complete Scaladoc API for 2.11.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, separate modules API is available at [the doc site](http://www.scala-lang.org/documentation/api.html) such as [xml here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala-xml/scala/xml/index.html).